# Fetch Device Details from C++ in BB10 Device

Tags: blackberry-10

I want to know how can I fetch the device details on a BB10 based device from C++ (details like Device Name, IP Address etc.)

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Most should be found on http://supportforums.blackberry.com and https://developer.blackberry.com and their sub-pages. Your question is hard to answer, because your examples for needed information are from different kind:

device name is readable in [`bb::device::HardwareInfo`](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__device__hardwareinfo.html)

IP address is another kind of information and found in any network information object, which refers to your choosen network API (do you use `QtNetwork` or other?). But you will be able to find your way to the right information at the link above.
**Note** that the IP address in your network infomation object on the device will be the LOCAL network address, and this will in most cases differ from that seen from any server point of view. You have to use an implementation of "whatismyip" (you can find PHP and other implementation) on a server, which is called by your device to find out your external IP address.